# Mixpanel track_links not working

Tags: javascript, html, mixpanel

I'm trying to use mixpanel track_links but it doesn't seems to work. I have this code html code snippet

```
<div class="mixpanel-book">
     <a href="https://mysite.com/?lid={{room.location_id}}&amp;floor={{room.floor}}" id="ggg" target="_blank">Book {{ room.name }} right now.</a>
 </div>
```

and my script is on the bottom of the page

```
mixpanel.track_links(".mixpanel-book a","test");
```

and it doesn't fire up any events. mixpanel.track() works fine. 
I have tried setting and id to the div and the a and using that as the query, still nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried adding the referrer? `mixpanel.track_links(".mixpanel-book a","test", {
        "referrer": document.referrer});`

Comment: Isn't that just an arbitrary property that you want to include in the analytics?

Comment: Hmm, maybe try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042957/mixpanel-track-links-does-not-work-with-dynamically-added-elements

Answer (score 0):

Track the link's id instead of the div's class. This should work:

`mixpanel.track_links("#ggg", "test");`

Comment: Why do you have to use an id?