# Can I use data attributes as a selectors for Mixpanel mixpanel.track_links?

Tags: mixpanel

According to [Mixpanel's documentation on mixpanel.track_links](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.track_links), I can pass in a selector (for their example they use an id), to select the link I'd like to track. I'm passing along some tracking to a client and want to know if I can use a HTML5 data attribute as a selector?

So the track event would look like this:

```
mixpanel.track_links("[data-blah='dude']", "Clicked Data Attribute");
```

HTML5 data attributes are query-able using document.querySelectorAll, althrough there is no support for IE8 <.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and it seems that you can't.

You can easily try, if you do something like:

```
mixpanel.track_links('#existing-id-on-page', '..') => true
```

the function will return `true` but if you do:

```
mixpanel.track_links('#non-existing-id', '..') => undefined
```

the function will return `undefined`, same as when you use `data-attributes`.

That's sad we can't use data attributes, classes are not made for targeting elements in JS...!
Anyway, I hope I answered your question!

Answer (score 0):

I created a Javascript (with Jquery) code that would recognize data attributes:

HTML: (The content of this attribute is a JSON string [EventName, Properties]. Caution: its recognize only double quotes)

`<a href="mailto:example@domain.com" data-mp-track='["Contact Click", {"Type" : "Email"}]'>Contact</a>`

Javascript:

```
$('a[data-mp-track]').on('click', function(event) {
  var callback, mp_details, new_tab, properties, that;
  that = this;
  new_tab = event.which === 2 || event.metaKey || that.target === '_blank';
  callback = function() {
    if (new_tab) {
      return;
    }
    window.location = that.href;
  };
  mp_details = JSON.parse(that.getAttribute('data-mp-track'));
  if (!new_tab) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(callback, 300);
  }
  properties = $.extend(mp_details[1], {
    'Page Title': document.title,
    'URL': window.location.pathname
  });
  mixpanel.track(mp_details[0], properties, callback);
});
```

Got some inspiration from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042957/mixpanel-track-links-does-not-work-with-dynamically-added-elements).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Needed to use a more advanced attributes selector. As long as it works with `document.querySelectorAll`, you can use that to add a class to those links like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-blah='dude']").forEach(function(foundlink) {
   foundlink.className += " blahdudelink";
});
```

And then the usual `mixpanel.track_links` call works:

```
mixpanel.track_links(".blahdudelink", "blah dude link click");
```